# Debugger is not attach to blackberry app due to net_rim_bb_gas.debug file is missing

Tags: blackberry-simulator

Hello Guys I have encountered a weirld problem I am not able to debug my blackberry app in eclipse due to net_rim_bb_gas.debug file is missing. I need your help....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can safely ignore this message otherwise the connection will timeout.  If you want to use advance debugging features that require debug files I would recommend you upgrade to the latest version of the BlackBerry Java SDK Eclipse Plug-in which downloads the debug files for you.